# javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I AM trying to catch all document click events, but i get error:

```
javascript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

this is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('body').onclick = function(e){
        var i=0;//for example
        }​// error over here
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid character here, directly after the curly bracket.

```
    }​// error over here
//  ^
```

Beside the problem of using the wrong object. You better address it with

```
document.body.onclick = ...
```

Comment: Actually there is an invalid character after the brace. If you copy the code in browser console, at least in Chrome, there is a red dot.

Comment: upvoted. But it is a problem happens with SO @Ibrahim . I face the same issue, in chat. It convert some characters to Red Dot

Comment: I tried to remove the red dot but keep the `document.getElementsByTagName('body').onclick = function` part and there is no error, even though getElementsByTagName returns a collection.

Comment: @Ibrahim it won't produce error. but won't work too. Try this in your console. `document.getElementsByTagName('body').onclick=function(){alert("aa");}`. It won't work

Comment: Agreed, it won't work, but the question was about `Invalid or unexpected token`. Anyway, I think @Nina's answer is the correct one since it gives a solution to both problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body').onclick
```

shold be

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick
```

because `getElementsByTagName` will return an HTML Collection

Comment: Not my downvote, but... What has this to do with the syntax error?

Comment: @Andreas - without a comment, s/he won't know how to improve the answer.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know why the character generates. Sometimes I found it in Chat too while sending code in chat.

Comment: You've given an answer on a not asked question. It's still wrong. There are easier (or correct) ways to add a click handler to the body but this is not the question/problem.